# Python issue with list (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list and I am comparing to check if certain set of values exist in that list and return back true or false.

Given below is what I have tried:

```
l1 = ['apples,oranges,bananas,pears']   <<- list 1
l2 = ['apples,'tomatoes']               <<- list 2
b2 = set(l1).intersection(l2)       <<- comparing the 2 lists
```

On performing the above I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I believe the above error means there is no data but I know the second list (l2) does have a value. Even if one value in the list matches I would like to get a True flag. Could anyone assist. Thanks

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please paste the _actual_ code you're running.

Comment: As you have typed it, `l2` is missing a single quote after the word `apples`. Not sure if that was just a typo here or actually in your code...

Comment: You have mistake in your list declaration. Make it like L1 = ['apples','oranges','bananas','pears']. Its working fine.

Comment: also paste the full error so we know where it happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting quotes, in both the lists.

```
l1 = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'pears']
l2 = ['apples','tomatoes']
b2 = set(l1).intersection(set(l2))
```

To elaborate, what you are comparing, in your example, are the strings 'apples,oranges,bananas,pears', 'apples', 'tomatoes' (with one quote supplied, else it would not compile). Clearly, the intersection of that sets is a null set. That is what you are getting, imo.

Answer (score 3):

Create your lists like below:

```
In [369]: l1 = ['apples','oranges','bananas','pears']
In [357]: l2 = ['apples','tomatoes']
```

And then do the intersection:

```
In [370]: set(l1).intersection(l2)
Out[370]: {'apples'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

This error occurs when your list is not iterable. That is when you have None object to iterate over it. There are multiple ways to handle the error, however, the best solution is

```
if not list:
  print('List object is not iterable as it is empty!!')
```

But in your case, it's a human error, which is not using quotes after the word/sentence ends.

```
l1 = ['apples','oranges','bananas','pears']  
l2 = ['apples','tomatoes']           
b2 = set(l1).intersection(l2)
```

This should do the trick. :)

Comment: The first two parts are incorrect. In the first part, lists are *always* iterable, even empty lists (iterating 0 times simply does nothing, but does not throw an error). The problem there is, as per the error message, that the object you are trying to iterate is `None`, which is clearly not a list or an iterable. In the second part, there's a syntax error: `If` -> `if`. And the correct way to check if an object `x` is a list is `if isinstance(x, list)`.

Comment: I do support @Fractalism 's comment tho, Please ensure that you get all the required info from the questioner before proceeding, As it might save effort